# Magento 2: How to add an "items per page switcher" to a pager in the current variations grid for a configurable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, adminhtml, grid, uicomponent

Then you open configurable product in admin panel there is Current Variations grid.
[image]

The grid is configured via `\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\ConfigurablePanel` class. How can I add an "items per page" switcher to the grid?

[image]

Comment: Hello Denis Óbukhov, You found Any Solution for that.